How to navigate back to CPQ quote line editor from LWC custom action
We are opening a lwc component with in Quote line editor, with the help of custom actions, not on finish button click on LWC, we want to close the pop up and navigate back to quote line editor screen, i tried access current tab id using workspace API and sforce console but no luck, am really stuck in this.
